Setting up Webpack Module Federation
For setting up Webpack Module Federation say for a React project, do we have any option apart from

Ejecting the React App and overriding the Webpack configs (e.g. overrideWebpackConfig) OR
Using CRACO to override the Webpack configs


Are you using CRA? If yes then you can try react-app-rewired

Yes...I am using CRA...

I assume react-app-rewired is similar to CRACO...in the sense of not requiring to eject and still able to override Webpack config

Actually my question is more in the sense of adopting Module Federation and if there is any way to incorporate that in the app without overriding Webpack config at all ?

You have to instruct your build tool to emit federated modules / where to load federated modules from - That is why you will need to play with the Webpack configuration

@KshitijV97 - So basically, for adding Webpack Module Federation support for any React app, "WE HAVE" to override Webpack configuration (be it via CRACO or ejecting/adding manually OR react-app-rewired which you pointed out) and it is not possible otherwise....

Yes you are right, We have to over ride, No alternative
